# Add Google Maps documentation for code completion in PhpStorm

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, phpstorm

I am developing a web application using PhpStorm and I use the Google Maps JavaScript API v3. PhpStorm offers a code completion feature but only if it knows about the library used, of course. So I would like to include the Google Maps library to PhpStorm in order to be able to use code completion but I do not know where to get the .js file from.
Does anybody know how to accomplish this task or know the URL for the js library?

Answer (score 21):

Here is what you have to do in PhpStorm (I was using 7.1, but the idea is the same).

Go [here](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/tree/master/contrib/externs/maps) and copy a file (I was selecting the latest version) to any directory you want (it will be used only by PhpStorm, not your app, so it does not really matter where will you save it).

After this go to **Files** -> **Settings** -> **JavaScript** -> **Libraries**. Then click **Add** and write the name, version and provide a link to your file (in a similar method as in my screenshot).

[image: PHPStorm's "New Library" dialog, filled in with the answerer's values. Name: googleMaps. Framework type: Custom. Version: 3.15. File name: googlemap_for_stormCompletion.js. Type: Debug.]

After clicking **Ok** and **Apply** everything should start to work.

Comment: Their repo have moved to Github, therefore pick the latest version of a file (library) from here from now on: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/tree/master/contrib/externs/maps

Comment: What about the Documentation URLs?  Is this necessary?

Comment: Thanks.  All my map code still shows validation errors.  Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Great, that worked like a charm. The @nik-sumeiko url is correct and currently update.

Answer (score 13):

There are stubs for Google Maps 3 for Visual Studio here:

http://gmapvsdoc.codeplex.com/releases/view/41099

I dropped the two javascript files into my IntelliJ 11 project, and it's not perfect, but helps reduce some warnings at least.  I'll update this post if I find anything better.

**Update on Jan. 25, 2013: something better!**

Google Maps stubs are available here:
http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/contrib/externs/maps/

**Update on Dec. 12, 2013**

The previous link points to a specific subversion revision.  A better link is https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/#git%2Fcontrib%2Fexterns%2Fmaps which shows all available stubs (there are more recent versions available now).

**Update, Nov. 2014**

The closure-compiler project is now on GitHub (thanks voltagex).  See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/tree/master/contrib/externs/maps.

Comment: FYI there is an IntelliJ ticket about Google Maps api stubs here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2767

Answer (score 12):

The `Google Maps` stubs can now be directly downloaded from PhpStorm, **File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Javascript > Libraries > Download**

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-7931) in PhpStorm tracker for this problem. You can try to configure the [stub library](https://github.com/dira/gmaps-stub), but you will not get any documentation, just less warnings in the code.